# trying to convert pfx in base64 string and asp.net core kestral certificate bindling throwing error

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, asp.net-core-webapi, kestrel

I have a certificate as `pfx` file, which I am trying to convert into a base64 string using the code below:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\tmp\localhost.pfx", "password");
var certBytes = cert.RawData;
var certString = Convert.ToBase64String(certBytes);
```

Now when trying to load this certificate for asp.net core app, kestral https certificate giving below error,

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key.'

What's wrong here?

```
public static void ConfigureHttps(HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions options)
    {
        var httpsCert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(File.ReadAllText(certPath)));
        options.ServerCertificate = httpsCert;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that when you create the pfx, you export both the public and private keys? An easy way to check is to import to cert store and see if it reports that both private and public key are present.

Comment: It's has both public and private key

Comment: Only thing I can think of is, RawData does not export private key. Worth manually getting bytes like this - cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pkcs12, "password");

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with this and it's working. `var certString = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\tmp\localhost.pfx"));
`